# How to fetchmail into specified folder?

Tags: shell

I installed fetchmail.

```
debian@debian:~$ fetchmail -p POP3 -u myaccount   pop.163.com
```

Enter password for myaccount@pop.163.com:
2 messages for myaccount at pop.163.com (23852 octets).
reading message myaccount@pop3.163.idns.yeah.net:1 of 2 (10814 octets) flushed
reading message myaccount@pop3.163.idns.yeah.net:2 of 2 (13038 octets) flushed

Where is my mail? how can i download it into /tmp?

Comment: If you have no `~/.fetchmailrc`, your mail was handed down to local MTA (that is, your local mailserver -- exim, postfix, ..., whatever listens on your localhost port 25). Set up your local mail properly before adding fetchmail to the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) will deliver to the local SMTP server. It is in its configuration that you need to decide where the mailbox is stored.